# how can i get same result for 22.5 inch and 10.6 inch 1080p display using HTML/CSS media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want same result for 22.5 inch display and 10.6 inch display both have 1080p (1920x1080) resolution
is there any specific method that I can follow up

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure what you are asking. Theoretically, the sizes are the same, so your result should be the same. However using media queries will help

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {/*your code here*/}
```

I am not sure you can fix your problem with media queries, if you gave more information I may be able to help.